# How to extract text to JLabel using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I haven't been coding for long and decided to write a program that would download the current Official Golf World Rankings [in PDF form](http://dps.endavadigital.net/owgr/doc/content/archive/2013/owgr49f2013.pdf) and then display the top 10 using JLabels.

While the program is able to download the file I have been unable to find out how to extract individuals cells from the table containing the data i.e extract "This Week", "Name", "Country" columns to individual arrays.

Could someone please give me some advice on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: It is not as easy as one might want it to be. The reason is that PDF predominantly is a Format for displaying, not for extracting. That being said you might want to try using the [PDFTextStripper](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html) as used in [ExtractText](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractText.java)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar, my code looks like this (using PDFBox):

```
PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\owgr49f2013.pdf"));
pdfParser.parse();
PDDocument pdDocument = pdfParser.getPDDocument();

PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper("UTF-8");
stripper.setSortByPosition(false);
stripper.setWordSeparator("###");
System.out.println(stripper.getText(pdDocument));
```

You'll need to extract the information you need from the resulting text with regular expressions or so.

Comment: Thank you for this code, could you please explain what the getPDDocument method does?

Comment: It gets the parsed PDF Document from the PDFParser as a PDDocument. See the PDFBox Api Docs here: http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser.html